# How to mix single-sided and double-sided pages to render in "dual view"?

Tags: double-sided, evince, single-sided

I would like to to generate a PDF that mixes single-side and double-sided pages that appear correctly within a PDF viewer when "Dual View" is selected in evince:

[image: dual view in evince]

(and the equivalent view/option in Adobe Acrobat)

For example say I have the following:

- cover
- pages 1 and 2 double-sided
- page 3 single sided left
- page 4 single sided left
- pages 5 and 6 double-sided
- page 7 single sided left
- page 8 single sided left

And starting off from this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[papersize={200mm,200mm},margin=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

% page#cover double sided
\eject
\pdfpagewidth=405mm
\pdfpageheight=200mm
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw node[inner sep=0] at ([xshift=202.5mm, yshift=-100mm] current page.north west) {
    \includegraphics[width=405mm, height=200mm]{example-image}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

% page#001-002 double sided
\eject
\pdfpagewidth=400mm
\pdfpageheight=200mm
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw node[inner sep=0] at ([xshift=200mm, yshift=-100mm] current page.north west) {
    \includegraphics[width=400mm, height=200mm]{example-image}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

% page#003 single sided left
\eject
\pdfpagewidth=200mm
\pdfpageheight=200mm
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw node[inner sep=0] at ([xshift=100mm, yshift=-100mm] current page.north west) {
    \includegraphics[width=200mm, height=200mm]{example-image}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

% page#004 single sided right
\eject
\pdfpagewidth=200mm
\pdfpageheight=200mm
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw node[inner sep=0] at ([xshift=100mm, yshift=-100mm] current page.north west) {
    \includegraphics[width=200mm, height=200mm]{example-image}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

% page#005-006 double sided
\eject
\pdfpagewidth=400mm
\pdfpageheight=200mm
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw node[inner sep=0] at ([xshift=200mm, yshift=-100mm] current page.north west) {
    \includegraphics[width=400mm, height=200mm]{example-image}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

% page#007 single sided left
\eject
\pdfpagewidth=200mm
\pdfpageheight=200mm
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw node[inner sep=0] at ([xshift=100mm, yshift=-100mm] current page.north west) {
    \includegraphics[width=200mm, height=200mm]{example-image}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

% page#008 single sided right
\eject
\pdfpagewidth=200mm
\pdfpageheight=200mm
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw node[inner sep=0] at ([xshift=100mm, yshift=-100mm] current page.north west) {
    \includegraphics[width=200mm, height=200mm]{example-image}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would like to end up with a PDF that is viewable with the following layout in evince:

```
  |-------------|
  |    cover    |
  |-------------|

  |-------------|
  |   1 and 2   |
  |-------------|

  |-----| |-----|
  |  3  | |  4  |
  |-----| |-----|

  |-------------|
  |   5 and 6   |
  |-------------|

  |-----| |-----|
  |  7  | |  8  |
  |-----| |-----|
```

Is this possible? If so, what are the tex instructions to accomplish that?

Comment: Have you ever seen this behaviour in any PDF viewer?

Comment: No, that's why I've asked if this is possible - I'm not sure if it is. Specifics: I've seen documents working with double-sided pages where the pages have the same dimensions, and separately also seen documents with mixed sized pages... so it *might* be possible to combine the two

Comment: I fear, this must be implemented in the viewer

Comment: You could make every page double width and use flowfram to put two frames on one page.  This will not affect headers and footers, though.

Comment: hmm not familiar with flowfram, and hwo to do what you have described - do you think you could flesh that out in an answer @JohnKormylo?

Comment: also note that I'm not making use of headers and footers (see the MWE in question), and don't really need them

Comment: Evince does not support that custom complex layout, and I guess no other PDF viewer supports that.

Answer (score 1):

This shows how to create double pages using flowfram.  Note that `\textwidth` doesn't change with the frame width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[papersize={405mm,200mm},margin=0mm, noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\parindent=0pt
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{flowfram}
\newflowframe[1,2,4]{405mm}{200mm}{0pt}{0pt}
\newflowframe[3,5]{200mm}{200mm}{0pt}{0pt}
\newflowframe[3,5]{200mm}{200mm}{205mm}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{-12pt}% the first page is always off
% page#cover double sided
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=\textheight]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}\newpage

% page 2 double sided
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=\textheight]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}\newpage

% page 3 single sided left
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textheight]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}\newpage

% page 3.5 single sided right
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textheight]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}\newpage

% page 4 double sided
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=\textheight]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}\newpage

% page 5 single sided left
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textheight]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}\newpage

% page 5.5 single sided right
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textheight]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}\newpage

\end{document}
```